# Why the position of input within form have changed in browser?

Tags: html, templates, dom, browser, web

In the template file, I write like this

```
        % for name,sequence in NAME_SEQUENCE:

        <form id="ucsc_profile_form${sequence_counter}"
              action="${request.route_path('CF_profile_UCSC_adapter')}"
              method="GET" target="_blank">
            <input type="hidden" value="${species_short}" name="species">
            <input type="hidden" value="${chrom}" name="chrom">
            <input type="hidden" value="${start}" name="start">
        </form>
       ....

     % endfor
```

But when I use `firebugs` to check the html codes, they are rendered like this:

```
        <form id="ucsc_profile_form1"  action="${request.route_path('CF_profile_UCSC_adapter')}" method="GET" target="_blank">
        </form>
        <input type="hidden" value="${species_short}" name="species">
        <input type="hidden" value="${chrom}" name="chrom">
        <input type="hidden" value="${start}" name="start">
```

The strange thing is that the `<input>` element becomes out of `<form>`..

The original page can be viewed [here](http://cistrome.org/finder/site/result?did=1200&tf=AR&Gene_box=&all_gene=1&region_select=proximal&extend_bp_number=200&repeat_bp_number=150&primer=0), though the DOM structure looks wrong, the element of the form can still be submit..

Does anyone have ideas about this?

Comment: Your `<input>` tag are never closed. Does that make a difference?

Comment: @BuhakeSindi I don't think so. Because the example in W3Cshool isn't closed either.. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp

Comment: Strange, are you sure your web server is not serving an old version of your template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the link through the [W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org).  I see 674 HTML errors.

More often than not, these types of issues stem from Firebug becoming confused by errors elsewhere in the HTML.

In your case, you have `<form>` elements as children of `<table>` and `<input>` elements as direct children of `<tbody>`.

Fixing the above errors should get Firebug playing nice.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I added the full link in the description part.

Comment: It seems to work now.. The result is that I put `<form>` element into `<tbody>` , which is not allowed. I moved it into `<td>` to fix the problem.